# How to choose input for neural network classification?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a set of data for the absorption of light of different surfaces with respect to time. This is my training data and I know each curve belongs to which surface [(in this training data plot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usCJn.jpg), but I want to design a neural network classifier that can give an output corresponding to the input I feed.

I have never worked with classifiers, so I don't know how to start with this. I want to know how can to determine the features in my data set to use for classification? Is there a general procedure so that I can decide the features to use for classification for any arbitrary data? not just image and text classification, because most tutorials either discuss such problems or assume the input vector of the neural network is given.

Comment: Could you please give us more information about your data? Is your data an image? Or something elese?

Comment: I attached the data with the original post, its provided as a matlab plot for 19 different samples. You can click on the link to view it. Or do you mean the source of the data? Its as I mentioned, absorption of light with repect to time for different surfaces. For each sample the absoprtion rate is measured at differnt time intervals and plotted using matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a one size fits all method . The only thing that I've heard about that comes close to what you might be looking for is Principal component analysis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) but that may be far too complicated. This might be a better place to start (https://georgemdallas.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/principal-component-analysis-4-dummies-eigenvectors-eigenvalues-and-dimension-reduction/).

If you find that too complicated to begin with, working out some factors you think that differ in your data might be sufficient, as long as you have access to the raw data. These are just some ideas:

E.g. average gradient, offset, standard deviation, min gradient, max gradient and so on. Remember the fewer that can be used to differentiate the better.

Just run each line's raw data points through each factor and they'll become the inputs for the net. One input per factor which are of course normalised.

for the output you could have one neuron for each surface, the neuron that outputs the highest is your winner.

Comment: Thanks! You really gave me some insight! So I really need to find the factors that can describe the feautres of the data for a proper classification, those factors determine the number of inputs to my neural network? And I know about PCA but I don't know how it could help me in my problem, since my data is only 2 dimensional and I already know that time is irrelevant. So what purpose could it serve in this case? And you basically mean that

Comment: Yep. PCA is only really useful to reduce the number of inputs to the network (because fewer the better, not only for performance but generalisation etc) so I'd pick a few statistical values with your data in excel, (have a look at http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Statistical-Functions.html) and see how they differ, choose the ones that differ the most between each series but choose a few as you need. PCA can be used to find the most useful features out of the ones you've chosen (but not needed if you have chosen good features)